# NETWORK_SERVICE keeps returning to Windows 7 Local Group Policies

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I am attempting to reconfigure the Windows 7 group policies on a laptop using the Local Group Policy Editor. Several of the fields for User Rights Assignment are giving me trouble (Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment).

Whenever I remove the `LOCAL_SERVICE` or `NETWORK_SERVICE` identity from the security setting of some of the fields it comes right back when I restart the Local Group Policy Editor.

This is happening on fields like **Change the system time** and **Create global objects**. I would like to change these to `Administrator` or `none`, but the policy editor keeps bringing back the defaults or simply adding `LOCAL_SERVICE` and `NETWORK_SERVICE` back in.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: I would not alter those settings if I were you. Especially without proper knowledge of what those accounts do.  You'll likely break your OS installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Vista/Server 2008 introduced the notion of required privileges for (some) rights. For example, the policy setting **Change the system time** requires the `LOCAL SYSTEM` identity to have access.

This is due to the service hardening introduced in Vista/2008 and the removal of a user's ability to be in Session 0. As a result, these special identities need these User Rights in order for the OS to run properly.